# Compile Time Error

Tags: arrays, swift, string, compiler-errors

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let dic = dict as Dictionary
    let z = "Period \(String(Int(indexPath.row + 1)))" // something wrong with this
    let x: Array = dic[z] as! Array
    if (x[0] is String) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = x[0] as? String
    } else {
        print("Error: it isnt a string")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
    return cell
```

What is wrong with this I feel like it is something simple but I just can't see it if you can see can you please help me! Thank you.

When I run this I get a segmentation fault and I have narrowed it down to this code. Again pls help. ;-;

Comment: Use the debugger and narrow the issue down to the exact line.

Comment: And what is the compile-time error mentioned in your title? The body of your question seems to be about a run-time error.

Comment: @rmaddy I have done what the guy below me told me to do and then it says "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" on the line let x: Array = dic[z] as! Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
let z = "Period \(indexPath.row + 1)"
```

You don't need all of the casts. `IndexPath.row` is already an `Int` and there's no need to create a `String` from the `Int`.

You also have a few other serious issues. Assuming this code is in your `cellForRowAt` method, NEVER call `reloadData()` there. Just return a cell. Don't do anything else to the table in that method.

You should also properly dequeue a cell from the tableview. It will make your table view much more efficient.

Comment: how do I dequeue a cell? I also edited the castings and it still gives me an error.

Comment: alright I did what you said and now  it says "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" on the line let x: Array = dic[z] as! Array and the compile error is gone.

Comment: You should declare `dic` as a dictionary of a specific type.

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't work @rmaddy. and then I get the same error thank you for helping me.

Comment: There are many existing discussions about the subscript error. Search through those. If you still need help with that issue, post a new question specific to that problem.

Comment: I fixed it... Thanks